# Print in rows for selected greps in sequence of lines

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed

I have file like below, with few hundreds of lines:

```
$ cat file1
TAP 1.0
.1.2.3.0 .0.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.1 .1.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.2 .2.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.3 .3.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.4 .4.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.5 .5.3.2.1.1
TAP 1.0
.1.2.3.0 .0.3.2.1.2
.1.2.3.1 .1.3.2.1.2
.1.2.3.2 .2.3.2.1.2
.1.2.3.3 .3.3.2.1.2
.1.2.3.4 .4.3.2.1.2
.1.2.3.5 .5.3.2.1.2
TAP 1.0
.1.2.3.0 .0.3.2.1.3
.1.2.3.1 .1.3.2.1.3
.1.2.3.2 .2.3.2.1.3
.1.2.3.3 .3.3.2.1.3
.1.2.3.4 .4.3.2.1.3
.1.2.3.5 .5.3.2.1.3
.....
```

From above file, I need to grep only two ".1.2.3.1" and ".1.2.3.0" and print as below:

```
    (( Desired Output))
    .1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1 
    .1.3.2.1.2 .0.3.2.1.2 
    .1.3.2.1.3 .0.3.2.1.3     
....
```

My code works out just for grepping particular string as below with below awk:

s1 output is below, where it grepping for .1.2.3.1 and giving output of all columns except 1st column as below:

```
command:  s1= cat $file1 | grep -i '.1.2.3.1' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
O/P(Output):
.1.3.2.1.1
.1.3.2.1.2
.1.3.2.1.3
```

In same way s2 is giving output as above for grepping .1.2.3.0 as below:

```
command: s2= cat $file1 | grep '.1.2.3.0' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
O/P:
.0.3.2.1.1
.0.3.2.1.2
.0.3.2.1.3
```

So complete output for s1 and s2 will be as below when I run simultaneously(***this is not I want***):

```
s1= cat $file1 | grep -i '.1.2.3.1' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
s2= cat $file1 | grep '.1.2.3.0' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
O/P:
.1.3.2.1.1
.1.3.2.1.2
.1.3.2.1.3
.0.3.2.1.1
.0.3.2.1.2
.0.3.2.1.3
```

I need output as below, how can I print my above as below:(***Should be as below***)

```
Desired Output:
    .1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1
    .1.3.2.1.2 .0.3.2.1.2
    .1.3.2.1.3 .0.3.2.1.3
    .. etc
```

Output should be in "echo $s1 $s2" format itself, but output should be as above with some loop condition by reading and printing one variable of S1 and S2 at a time, instead of printing all S1 first followed by all S2 grepped output.

So I need to keep every read variable temporarily in S1 and S2 and print one by one in sequence as above.

So above output will come only when, if it does below in script:

```
- First grepped output of .1.2.3.1 should be kept in variable s1
- First grepped output of .1.2.3.0 should be kept in variable s2
then print both first grepped one's of both temporary string as echo $s1 $s2 as below:
.1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1
- Do in the same way for second grepped temporary output for both as below:
.1.3.2.1.2 .0.3.2.1.2
- Do in the same way for all Nth grepped output as below:
.1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1
.1.3.2.1.2 .0.3.2.1.2
....
.1.3.2.1.Nth .0.3.2.1.Nth
```

For all sequence it should print by consider one grep at a time, instead of all grepped output.

As for your better understanding it works out better for one line for particular grep as below:

```
[root@server]$cat file0
.1.2.3.0 .0.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.1 .1.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.7 .3.3.2.1.1



[root@server]$ s1=`cat file0 | grep -i '.1.2.3.1' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
[root@server]$ s2=`cat file0 | grep '.1.2.3.0' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
host$ echo $s1 $s2
.1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1
```

But how it works for "file1" like "file0" and how can I print as above!!

Thanks!

Comment: are you ignoring the first token in the input file?  Also, what if there are more than one record satisfying the condition?

Comment: I have no idea what the mapping is between the input you posted and the output you posted. Hopefully others will be able to figure it out but you might want to add an explanation to your question.

Comment: Try `sed 's/.*\(tap.*\)/.1.3.2.1.\1 .0.3.2.1.\1/;p;N;N;d' tap.file`, and then consider how you could improve the question.

Comment: I modified question bit, its for more records(not fixed) and also *tap* I mentioned just for understanding on how the sequence goes, my question is how to read each grep of both s1 and s2 and keep as temporary variable inside and print both (like: echo $s1 $s2). Please let me know if this is bit clear.

Comment: `s1= cat $file` is the same as `cat $file`. `grep -i '.1.2.3.1'` is the same as `grep '.1.2.3.1'`. `cat $file | grep '.1.2.3.1'` is the same as `grep '.1.2.3.1' $file`. `grep '.1.2.3.1' $file | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'` is the same as `awk '/.1.2.3.1/{$1=""; print $0}'`. None of this makes any sense. What are `s1` and `s2` supposed to be? Why do none of the outputs match up?

Comment: s1 , s2, echo, I tried mentioning just for understanding, that is not working, if its just one line that will work.      But in our current case s1 will give few hundred as it's just grep, even s2 also gives few hundred as its just grep, also my echo will also not work here as its not reading one grep and keep in some tem variable to print using echo.   We will not get echo output because as desired because it grepping for all.  Please check my modified summary, hope it may help on my expectation. Thanks!

Comment: [root@server]$cat file0
.1.2.3.0 .0.3.2.1.1
.1.2.3.1 .1.3.2.1.1

[root@server]$ s1=`cat file0 | grep -i '.1.2.3.1' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
[root@server]$ s2=`cat file0 | grep '.1.2.3.0' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
host$ echo $s1 $s2
.1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1

Comment: My requirement is bit complex, so I have tried simplifying the question a lot for all people understanding.  I think this will be bit easy for all understanding, pls let me know if this helps along with other posts by @Beta

Comment: Any inputs, please let me know for any details for any simplification further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single `awk` script that do the task:

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {FS = "[\r ]"}     # input line field separator <CR> or <SPACE>
/TAP/ && NR > 1{print output; output = ""} # print output when matched TAP (but not first line), then reset output
/^.1.2.3.[10]/ {output = $2 OFS output} # if matched pattern, left pad 2nd input field to output
END {print output} # print the final outuput
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
.1.3.2.1.1 .0.3.2.1.1
.1.3.2.1.2 .0.3.2.1.2
.1.3.2.1.3 .0.3.2.1.3
```